# JS/Yup validate with multiple rules

Tags: javascript, regex, yup

There is number field which have validation regex = user is able to enter numbers between 0 and 364.

If you enter number which is not in that range you get specific error message.

Now I need to add on same field validation rule that if numbers have two digits and first is 0.

Then show errors messages specific for that rule.

```
// 0 to 364 (days of the year) + format number cannot be in this format 02:
  const yearRegex = /^(?:36[0-4]|3[0-5]\d|[12]\d{2}|[0-9]\d?)$ | ^0[0-9].*$/

  totalDaysPaid: Yup.string().matches(yearRegex, totalDaysPaidErrorMsg),
```

This is regex for both rules in one: /^(?:36[0-4]|3[0-5]\d|[12]\d{2}|[0-9]\d?)$ | ^0[0-9].*$/

How to make this validation to be conditional, if days are not in range set message1.

And if format is wrong, set message2 ?

Comment: The spaces in the pattern are meaningful. Remove them.

Comment: That didn't help.

Comment: Sure, but at least the pattern will start making sense. You cannot expect a space to appear after the string end or before its start. To solve the problem, you most probably need to separate these two alternatives into separate regexps and associate with appropriate error messages. That is the most usual way to deal with these kinds of issues.